# OS-wide text autocomplete service with popup

Tags: user-interface, autocomplete, operating-system, popup, transliteration

Consider something like [Google Input Tools](https://www.google.com/inputtools/) for instance, which can transliterate text in multiple languages using the Latin script. As you type a word, it interactively autocompletes it, showing you multiple possible results.

My question is, do the major OSs (i.e. Linux, macOS and Windows) enable developers to implement something like [Google Input Tools](https://www.google.com/inputtools/) system-wide? Such that a user can get the autocomplete service with a popup next to any text input field in any OS application?

The "autocomplete popup" needn't appear automatically, but could rather be enabled with a keyboard shortcut. Moreover, it needn't modify the target text field itself in real-time, but rather use a buffer of its own that can be easily copied to the original text field. Thus the ability to (1) detect the text field the cursor is located in and (2) copy text to said text field could be paired with the UI of something like Spotlight on macOS to achieve decent results.

However, I lack any knowledge about OS user-interface programming and thus I'm unsure if what I'm trying to achieve here is *universally* supported by all major OSs.